# Why didn't work the erase and rename?

Tags: pascal

I do laboratory work and i need to convert original file by a certain algorithm. Here is my code:

```
var f1,f2: text;

procedure rounds(var f1, f2: text);
  var a: real;
  begin
    while not EoF(f1) do
      begin
        read(f1, a);
        write(f2, a:0:1, ' ');
      end;
  end;

begin
  assign(f1, './lab.txt');
  reset(f1);
  assign(f2, './temp'); rewrite(f2);
  rounds(f1,f2);
  close(f1);
  close(f2);
  Erase(f1);
  rename(f2, 'lab.txt');
end.
```

Why not deleted f1 and f2 is not renamed?
And I can use only sequential files

Comment: Because you're closing those files before those operations.

Comment: The files **must** be closed before they can be erased or renamed (see my answer below). It's mandatory for ``Erase()`` and ``Rename`` to not have them opened.

Comment: @user1438038, true, but closing *unassigns* them. That was my point.

Comment: I tried your code with FPC v2.6.4 and it works fine, as is.  So, maybe your problem is some kind of lock on either file, perhaps read-only attribute or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your files are not opened by any application. From the FreePascal documentation:

> Erase removes an unopened file from disk. The file **should be assigned with Assign, but not opened** with Reset or Rewrite.

```
Program EraseDemo;

Var MyFile: Text;

begin
  Assign(MyFile, 'demo.txt');
  Rewrite(MyFile);
  Writeln(MyFile, 'Lorem Ipsum dolor est');
  close (MyFile);

  Erase(MyFile);
end.
```

> Rename changes the name of the assigned file F to S. **F must be assigned, but not opened.**

```
Program RenameDemo;

Var MyFile: Text;

begin
  Assign(MyFile, paramstr(1));
  Rename(MyFile, paramstr(2));
end.
```